# Getting a expression output

Tags: python, python-3.6

This program will help us practice input validation and while loops.
The user will be asked to enter two numbers which will both be validated. The sum of the numbers will then be displayed in a complex print statement
and the user will be asked if they would like to run the program again. An example run is below

```
Please enter the first number: five
Invalid response. Please enter a whole number.
Please enter the first number: 5 Please enter the second number: 7
5 + 7 = 12
```

The output of a 'number1 + number2 = number3' i am not sure where to go with this. Everything else is coming out just right I just don't know how to end it. Thanks for the help.

```
while True:
  print('Please enter the first number. ')
  num1 = input() 
  if num1.isdigit(): 
    break 
  else: 
    print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number. ') 
    print() 
while True: 
  print('Please enter the second number: ') 
  num2 = input()  
  if num2.isdigit(): 
    break  
  else: 
    print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number') 
    print() 
sum = str(num1) + str(num2) 
print sum
```

Comment: Please add some of your code so far so amendments can be made.

Comment: while True:
        print('Please enter the first number. ')
        num1 = input()

        if num1.isdigit():
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number. ')
            print()
while True:
        print('Please enter the second number: ')
        num2 = input()

        if num2.isdigit():
            break
        else:
                print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number')
                print()

sum = str(num1) + str(num2)
print sum

Comment: @brewr012 please [edit] that into your question

Comment: while True:
        print('Please enter the first number. ')
        num1 = input()

        if num1.isdigit():
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number. ')
            print()
while True:
        print('Please enter the second number: ')
        num2 = input()

        if num2.isdigit():
            break
        else:
                print('Invalid response. Please enter a whole number')
                print()

sum = str(num1) + str(num2)
print sum

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to print out the entire equation:

```
print("%s + %s = %s" % (number1, number2, number3))
```

is probably what you need. https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting can explain more in-depth what's happening there, essentially the "%s" are replaced by the items in the tuple following the "%" called on the string.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
`sum = "%s + %s = %i" %(num1,num2,int(num1)+int(num2))`